# Can a Vertex AI custom prediction model (docker) read from Cloud Storage FUSE?

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

According to the documentation, you can [use Cloud Storage FUSE during training](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/cloud-storage-file-system-ai-training). However, I cannot find in the documentation if the filesystem is also available during inference.

My goal is to load various pre-trained models from GCS. I do not want to package these models (huggingface) into the Docker image, so I am able to make changes to these models without pushing the entire image.

Comment: It's a bad idea. it's better to have a container per version of your model(s) (you can put several model in your container and have a dynamic routing to select the right one according to the query). The idea here is the easiness of rollback in case of issue, model skew,...

Comment: You can give Vertex AI Model Registry a path to your model files. The model files then get copied to a managed bucket to ensure the easiness of rollback you mentioned. But I was having struggles accessing that managed bucket from my code.